# saving multiple user input variables to be used later in scheduled task

Tags: c#, sql, variables, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to figure out the best way to run my scheduled task. My program finds a database backup file and restores it to a different location. But I can only restore backups after 5pm daily. I need the first part of my program (which is a web form with user input from a dropdown) to save a few variables to be used later when the scheduled task is triggered (after 5pm everyday).

The second part of the program takes the user inputted variables from first part and runs the second part of the program (a database restore). The problem I am having is figuring out where and how to store the variables from the first part of program? * This first form may be sent multiple times. Meaning I would need to retrieve the variables saved from first part to use in second part.

Also, trying to figure out how to run the second part of program until all the saved variables are used up, meaning when all databases selected from first part are restored. (It's a database restore so I can't loop the whole process. Some databases are very large).

First part of program, variables needing to be saved
-dbName(chosen from dropdown)
-backUpLocation(where the backup file is located)
-serverLocation(Server that user wants to restore to)

What second part of program does
After 5pm daily, copies files and unzips it to server that is designated in first part. Then restores it. Thanks for any help!

Comment: There are many ways to solve this problem, none of which is necessarily more correct than another.  Options include a database or a file.  Don't save the variables in memory (e.g. not in a static variable), because the app domain can recycle and the info would be lost.

Comment: Hi Eric, I am thinking a text file then, because the variables are simple. But if the app gets used say 10 times in one day. Then later (at 5pm) I need to restore those 10 databases for that day. How would you organize this on the text file to ensure i am reading the correct values in the second part of the app(after 5pm). Also how would you read through the variables in the second part until all the variables are used up and the app can stop? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I like to use [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/) or just a regular old XML file using [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) for this sort of state persistence. Do you have any special requirements out of how/where you store these values?

Comment: No special requirement. I'm a little new to this. Can you give me an example of how i would call the variables from the second part of application (right now i have a second web form that displays what process the restore is going through). And how would i exhaust all variables that are inputted from the first form besides using a loop? Thanks.

Comment: This is well covered ground with a basic search. The  LINQ to XML url provided will give you exhaustive references for reading and working with values once you have an XElement loaded up. XElement provides Save() and Load() methods for dealing with the xml file itself:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement_methods(v=vs.110).aspx